# How can I cope with my disappointment after not receiving a bonus?

Tags: performance-reviews, bonus

We just had our compensation meetings at the bank I work at (in a support position), and after being told I had met management's expectations, I was given neither a bonus nor a raise.  The reason was they were told by senior management that those people who exceeded expectations should be given a larger bonus, and if that meant that others got nothing then so be it. This has left me angry and feeling like I wasted the past year, and I'm looking for a new job.

**How do I deal with my disappointment in my current job until I find something else?** I don't feel motivated to do anything but the bare minimum but I don't want to drag my feet so much that my job is at risk.

Comment: Did you get paid for the last year?  Then it was not a waste.

Comment: Why do you feel that you wasted a year?  You worked, and presumably got paid, which allowed you to at least keep food on the table and a roof over your head, which is IMHO one of the main reasons for working.  Seems like your management was perfectly open with you: you met expectations (which means you didn't get fired), and bonuses are for people who exceed expectations.

Comment: OP, I've drastically edited your question to focus it on your central question and make it something that can be answered instead of a general "what do I do?" advice question.

Comment: Dear OP, most people here don't work in banking and won't understand that it's normal to have a "variable component" (ie. a bonus) as part of your compensation. Unless there are exceptional reasons, or you screwed up royally, it's expected to get some additional money. I don't think there's any alternative to looking for a new job.

Comment: There's a variable component in many jobs these days. But the rules under which the company allocates that money change frim year to year depending on available budget and what the company wants the money to do. If the goal is to retain employees, it gets distributed more widely; if the goal is to reward top employees and encourage others to up their game it gets spread less widely.

Comment: @TheMathemagician, you are wrong about that. Many companies have bonuses and many, many banking employees do not ever get a bonus. Senior banksters are often more likely to get a bonus, but tellers and programmers and branch managers and admin support and HR and any clerical positions are in no way guaranteed a bonus. Of course many of us think that senior managers who run their companies into he ground for short-term personal profit shouldn't get bonuses either and they certainly should not get large bonuses when all employees with decent performance can't get a cost of living raise.

Comment: OP, sometimes in life you need to expect less.

Answer (score 11):

> Saying that I am angry, that I feed I wasted a year and of course
>   looking for another job would be an understatement.
>
> Anyone have any suggestions on how to deal in my current job until I
>   find something else? I see it being a fine line between doing the bare
>   minimum and doing so much less that my job is at risk (more so than
>   now)

Whenever I apply for a new job and am negotiating salary, I never include bonus money as a given.

The reason is that you have no real control. Barring exceptional conditions, you can depend on your salary. But your bonus is typically discretionary. It could disappear based on company performance, the judgement of others, or any number of other reasons. (That's one of the reasons companies divide compensation between salary and bonus. Bonuses can go away if business conditions dictate - salary not so much.)

In my most recent company, after we were acquired by a larger company, the rules for bonuses changed. I was given a pot of money for my department. I had to divide it up for my team. Now I happened to have a terrific team. If I wanted to give someone more than an average bonus, I had to give someone else less than average - even if they were all outstanding that year. The pool of money for raises worked in a similar manner. I divided it up as best I could, but I know I gave less to some workers than they deserved.

I suggest you quell your anger and continue working your usual routine as you seek a new job. If it helps, concentrate on the fact that you earned a salary (and thus the time wasn't actually wasted), and concentrate on all that you could lose if you cannot maintain control.

You could lose your dignity. You could lose your reputation. You could lose friends. You could lose a good recommendation. You could lose your job - and it's always worse to be seeking a new job when you aren't on a payroll. Financial need could lead you to accept whatever happens to come along - even if it's not a good job for you.

For your next job, consider focusing on the salary you can depend on, and not so much on the bonus which isn't under your control. Try to find a position where you can consistently exceed expectations, rather than just meeting them.

Comment: +1 for finding a position where you can consistently exceed, or improving in this position to consistently exceed. And be aware that there's always someone below the line and some years it's going to be you. It could be worse; in some businesses Exceeded isn't enough and you need to hit Greatly Exceeded.

Answer (score 4):

In most places, "meets expectations" means you deserved your salary. The company is happy they hired you because your produce the results that are expected. "Doesn't meet expectations" means you didn't quite deserve your salary. "Exceeds expectations" means you deserved more than your salary.

"Meets expectations" should be the normal state. If you are really good compared to your salary, you should get "exceeds expectations" and a bonus, and then probably should get a raise and increased "expectations" - the same performance with the higher salary will mean that the year after that you just "meet expectations", but at a higher level. Then hopefully you improve in what you're doing and the cycle starts again.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I deal with my disappointment in my current job until I find something else? I don't feel motivated to do anything but the bare minimum but I don't want to drag my feet so much that my job is at risk.

Your disappointment is completely understandable however foot dragging is an immature response to it.  You offer your services at a professional level.  The disappointment should not affect the way that you offer your services, just who you offer them to.  Don't get into the habit of lowering yourself to spite someone else.

Comment: Moreover, foot dragging is a good way to get ranked as "did not meet requireents" next time around.

Comment: True, if the OP is reviewed again before they find something else it would be a blackmark on them.  I guess it depends on local markets whether their job hunt will likely be that long.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know how you stack up with your peers. 
Objectively , the company thinks you are not up there with them and went with their policy of rewarding employees who have exceeded the expectations.
This means you need to work harder to get there. You might feel you have done an excellent job but there might be others who have done better.
This should drive you to get a new job if you think it is unfair or you should motivate yourself to do better than others by working even harder.
As for waste of 1 year , you surely must have learned many things at work and added to your experience besides earning salary . Maybe the most important thing you learned is managing your expectations. Best wishes.

Comment: Sometimes it's not even working harder, but getting better at what you are doing, which could be a natural process with time. And "meets expectations" is not an absolute rating, it compares what you do to your salary. If you managed to get 10% more salary than your colleague, you can do exactly the same amount and quality of work, and he "exceeds" while you only "meet" - more salary equals higher expectations.

Answer (score 0):

The most productive thing you can do is ask your boss what specific things you need to accomplish to get a raise and bonus next year. The worst thing you can do is perform more poorly. It is possible that it is time to move on, but likely this will be no better anywhere else until you address the root of why you are not rated as exceeding expectations or higher. Further by showing the maturity to learn from this experience and grow, you will improve your odds for next year. Managers like it when you take constructive criticism to heart and make significant improvements.

You also need to stop thinking you are entitled to either raises or bonuses. In the course of a career, you will get them some years and not others and sometimes for nothing under your control. I once worked for a company that gave no raises for 4 years due to a downturn in the economy. As no one else locally was giving raises either, there was little point in moving on.

Other times perhaps your perceptions of your performance and your boss's perceptions are not the same. You need to be well aware of what your boss thinks long before it is time for raises and bonuses. If you disagree with his perception, you need to find a way to change it because **his perception** is what will give you a raise or bonus not the other way around. Further, in many companies, it is not just your boss's call, it is something negotiated between senior managers and they will not reward the people they never heard of. To consistently get raises and bonuses, you need to be considered to be a top performer within your group and to the company at large.

You need to remember that you are in competition for raises and bonuses with your fellow employees and that you have to be in the top to qualify some years. When there is more money available for these things, you can afford to be lower in the rating scale, but being in the top is the only way to improve your chances of getting a raise consistently.

Comment: In the past, everyone not rated as unacceptable got a cost of living raise. Those days are gone. I have seen cases where exceeds expectations is not enough for a raise, you have to be rated as Outstanding.  I have even seen times when people get promoted with no pay increase, something that would have been unheard of when I was young. In the current climate, the best way to get a significant raise is to move to another company. Companies have done this to themselves by converting salary increase budgets into stockholder profits, so don't feel guilty to moving on to make more money.